# NSAttributedString with over line

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I want to describe and render an overline (vs underline) using a `NSAttributedString`.  I don't see any attribute to accomplish this.  Is there a way to offset an underline or strikethrough line to simulate what I want?  If not, do I need to define and render a custom attribute?  Any other options?

Comment: Did you find a good way to do this?

Comment: @rene - no; I ended up taking an entirely different approach.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know! So far I'm working around it by inserting a single line (a separate paragraph) with whitespace that has strikethrough.

Comment: @TomSwift would you be willing to share how you did it? I've posted a similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65472535/how-can-i-draw-an-overline-in-a-uilabel