# How can I draw an overline in a UILabel?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to draw an overline (as opposed to strikethrough or underline) within a UILabel. So far I have not seen any direct way to implement this using NSAttributedString. Is there any way to do overlines in UILabel?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good solution of your problem.

Create a subclass of UILabel, may be, OverlineLabel. Create a view in the class that sticks to the top of the label, and is of equal width of the label itself, and is of height 1 or 0.5 (as you see it comfortable). Add the view as subview when `text` property is not nil. And don't forget to remove it when `text` is nil.